# A pop-up window on Windows cannot be closed permanantly, how can I fix it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, download, window

I'm using windows and have the following issue:

A pop-up window on Windows cannot be closed permanantly, no matter how often I click "don’t show this dialogue again" and close the window. It appears again after a few minutes. How can I close the window?

Here is the pop-up-window:

[image]

Comment: Internet-Download-Manager : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Download_Manager

Comment: Update Lantern https://lantern.io/ and then disable it from autostarting if that is not necessary  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-which-apps-run-automatically-at-startup-in-windows-9115d841-735e-488d-e749-9ba301d441e6

Comment: Considering that’s an IDM window I would simply stop using IDM. This is clearly a case of IDM not respecting its own settings. Why would a VPN help in this case? Just uninstall IDM….

Comment: @Ramhound IDM is doing nothing wrong. It is Lantern that is trying to download this file. Google the URL in the screenshot.

Comment: @Gantendo - Is Latern doing the download or the author is downloading a .gz from the website?

Comment: @Ramhound Lantern is attempting to download the file, and failing over and over again (error 525: SSL Handshake Failed which is a Cloudflare http status code). IDM probably does not know how to deal with this Cloudflare-specific error code and tries again, but it is not the source of the problem.

Comment: Where are you getting error 525? That screenshot suggests the file was downloaded.

Comment: @Ramhound Good point. Visiting that url in the browser returns a 525 tho (for me).